# Gradle project test depends on another project's test

Tags: gradle

This might be a duplicate somewhere but some of the answers were for old Gradle which doesn't work anymore. Please let me know if this is doable. I have a new project named `NewProject` . `NewProject` depends on `common` project which lives in another directory.

```
- NewProject
  - \build.gradle
  - \settings.gradle
  - \src
    - \main\java
    - \test\java

 
- common
  - \build.gradle
  - \settings.gradle
  - \src
    - \main\java
    - \test\java
```

In `NewProject`, my file `settings.gradle` looks like this

```
rootProject.anme = 'NewProject'

include ':common'
project(':common').projectDir = file('../common')
```

and my file `build.gradle` has below lines in *dependencies* section

```
dependencies {
   implementation project(':common')
   ...
   testImplementation project(':common')
   ...
}
```

The problems I have are two:

- Because I don't own the common project code, so I can not change the build file in common.
- My test in `NewProject` couldn't locate the common's test classes. For example `BaseTest` etc.

I have tried approaches of:

- Using `testImplementation project(':common:test')` doesn't work because `':common:test'` is not recognized.
- Using `testImplementation project(':common').sourceSets.output.classes`, but this approach is invalid for Gradle 5.0 and above.

Please let me know if there are other ways of doing this!

Answer (score 0):

What is needed ?
The test-classes and test-resources dir of `:common` need to be in the classpath of the `:newProject` test

A way for your setup via Local dir access - in the `:newProject` build.gradle

```
testImplementation files('../common/build/classes/java/test')
testImplementation files('../common/build/resources/test')
```

note: this does not transitively add `:common` test dependencies to `:newProject` test, you have to do that manually.